# Regex capturing group with many repeating white spaces

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have an issue capturing this kind of groups where:

```
a1:b1 a2:b2 b3 b4 a3:b5
```

and the expected result is

```
a1:b1
a2:b2 b3 b4
a3:b5
```

the best expression I could get is `/[\w]*:([\w]*)/g` and this is what i get :

```
a1:b1
a2:b2
a3:b5
```

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]+\d+:.*?(?=\s*[a-zA-Z]+\d+:|$)`? See https://regex101.com/r/hJQFcn/1

Comment: Thank you soo much, working as intended, i switch it to \w+:.*?(?=\s*\w+:|$). I never used the look ahead but it is a pretty cool feature.

Comment: Just a thought but can't you split by `\s(?=\w+:)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
\w+:.*?(?=\s*\w+:|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJQFcn/2).

*Details*:

- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `:` - a colon
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\w+:|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires zero or more whitespaces, one or more word chars and a colon, or end of string, immediately to the right of the current location.